# Количество соединений nginx-rtmp-module

Tags: nginx, rtmp

Каким образом можно посчитать максимальное количество соединений, которые сможет держать nginx? Стрим, допустим, в 720p, CPU - какой-нибудь 4-ядерник на ~3.5ГГц. Спасибо

Comment: Он практически ничего не делает, если только вы не запускаете ffmpeg на вебсервере. То есть я бы предполагал просто из доступной полосы и из битрейта транслируемого видео. Ну, процентов 10-15 на всякие оверхеды.

Comment: да, видео будет кодироваться на сервере